# Add comment on LinkedIn update as company

Tags: linkedin-api

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_comment

As documented in the above link, I'm trying to add a comment on behalf of company. I'm using the 'DevTestCo' test company page given by LinkedIn.

- When I'm using 'PUT' request type, I'm getting following error.

  "Unsupported PUT target {/v1/companies/2414183/updates/key=UPDATE-c2414183-6004871959874150400/update-comments-as-company}"
- Then I used 'POST' request type, then I'm getting following error.

  "Can't post comment as company, [memberId: .....] is not an admin of [companyId: 2414183]."

How can I request to become an admin for 'DevTestCo' page? or any other way I can test adding comment on update.

Thanks

Comment: Created my own company page & tested